# "Картата потата": що означає вираз?

Tags: значення-слів

У Києві є кафе, що називається "**Картата Потата**". Цікавить що означає цей вираз? У [СУМ-20](http://sum.in.ua/s/kartatyj) знайшла лише те, що означає "***картатий***":

> Із чотирикутними візерунками, малюнками.
>
> Ходкевич витяг *картату* червону хустку і витер спітнілу голову (Зінаїда Тулуб, Людолови, II, 1957, 133).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У [Академічному  тлумачному словнику (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/kartatyj)  знаходимо:

> КАРТА́ТИЙ, а, е. Із чотирикутними візерунками, малюнками (про тканину,
>   одяг і т. ін.). На Марині плахта — аж очі на себе бере: картата,
>   червчата, шовком заткана (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 225); На другому
>   тракторі сидить юнак. На ньому картата сорочка й капелюх (Юрій
>   Яновський, II, 1954, 233); Ходкевич витяг картату червону хустку і
>   витер спітнілу голову (Зінаїда Тулуб, Людолови, II, 1957, 133).

Потата, очевидно, з англ. «potato»- картопля [META Перекладач з Англійської на Українську](http://translate.meta.ua/ua/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0/).  Це слово у словосполученні «Картата Потата» - це матеріальне (лексичне) запозичення - запозичення, за якого з іноземної в рідну мову входить лексична одиниця повністю (значення й експонент). [Вступ до мовознавства - Кочерган М.П. - Запозичення](http://westudents.com.ua/glavy/9817-zapozichennya.html).

Отже, це «картопля з чотирикутними візерунками». Думаю, автори цього проекту не дуже «заморочувалися» і не намагалися вкласти у назву надто глибокий зміст. Це назва кулінарного шоу, то, очевидно, має зв’язок з  картоплею, приготованою таким способом: [Чіпси шкода або користь](http://vidpoviday.com/chipsi-shkoda-abo-korist).

Answer (score 4):

Ось як [пояснює назву](http://inter.ua/ru/news/2006/08/28/1491) проекту "Картата Потата" його автор:

*"Картата потата" - це картата картопля, в перекладі з західно-українського діалекту.*